# Magento Product Collection exclude category

Tags: magento, collections, categories

I need to exclude a category from my productCollection but I dont know how to achieve this.

Requirements:

- Only visible products
- Ordered by: created_at DESC
- Exclude category id 43
- Limit 4 (products)

To retrieve my collection I use the following code:

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
                ->setVisibility(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->getVisibleInCatalogIds());



$collection =  $this->_addProductAttributesAndPrices($collection)
                    ->addAttributeToSort('created_at', 'DESC')
                    ->setPageSize(4)
                    ->setCurPage(1);
```

This works fine, but I can't add this filter:

```
->addFieldToFilter('category_id', array('nin' => array('43')))
```

---

I found these similar questions, but they wont solve my problem.

[How to exclude a category from a magento getCollection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9538123/how-to-exclude-a-category-from-a-magento-getcollection)

[Magento - How do I exclude a category from product collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13083576/magento-how-do-i-exclude-a-category-from-product-collection?lq=1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try below code:

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');         
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1); // Enable products
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4); // Visible products 
$collection->addAttributeToSort('created_at', 'DESC') // Order by created_at DESC
           ->setPageSize(4) // Number of products
           ->setCurPage(1); // set page size
$catId = 43; // category id to exclude
$collection->getSelect()->join(array('cats' => 'catalog_category_product'), 'cats.product_id = e.entity_id'); // Join with category on product/entiry id
$collection->getSelect()->where('cats.category_id!=?',$catId); // exclude category from collection

echo '<pre>';
echo $collection->getSelect(); // See sql query
print_r($collection->getData()); Print collection in array format
```

Hope will help!

Comment: thanks for your reply, but it does not work. I've got the following exception: `exception 'Exception' with message 'Item (Mage_Catalog_Model_Product) with the same id "6130" already exist' in /lib/Varien/Data/Collection.php:373`

Comment: Try again after changing `$collection` to `$customCollection` every where in code.

Comment: Still does not work, same error! I am using magento version 1.7.0.2

Comment: Finally got it working! It's because there are duplicated primary keys. I had to group the query on e.entity_id. Thanks for your help Rajiv :) - I've added it into your answer

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Rajiv's answer as Martijn didn't include the group by, a full working example is:

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');         
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1); // Enable products
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4); // Visible products 
$collection->addAttributeToSort('created_at', 'DESC') // Order by created_at DESC
       ->setPageSize(4) // Number of products
       ->setCurPage(1); // set page size
$catId = 43; // category id to exclude
$collection->getSelect()->join(array('cats' => 'catalog_category_product'), 'cats.product_id =         e.entity_id'); // Join with category on product/entiry id
$collection->getSelect()->where('cats.category_id!=?',$catId); // exclude category from collection
$collection->getSelect()->group(array('e.entity_id')) // Group by e.entity_id to prevent Item with the same id already exists.. Exception

echo '<pre>';
echo $collection->getSelect(); // See sql query
print_r($collection->getData()); Print collection in array format
```

Comment: Works perfect, I had to add the trailing ; to  the group array line though for it to work. Thanks!